# How do I add key randomly from a list and value from another list but on the same index number in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I have two lists namely states and capitals. As you can guess they have state names and their capitals. Also, the capital of state at position 0 in the state list is at position 0 in the capitals list.

I am able to randomly pick a state from the state list and store it in a variable named s.

What I want to do is pick the corresponding capital from the capitals list and store it in a variable named c.

I then plan to add these pairs into a dictionary in the following way -

```
corrent_dict.update({s:c})
#correct_dict is the dictionary's name
#s and c are the previously mentioned variables
```

What I am not able to do is get the corresponding capital name from the capital list. I would like help with that.

```
['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona']
```

Are the states in the states list.

```
['Montgomery', 'Juneau', 'Phoenix']
```

Are the capitals in the capitals list.

As you can see the states and the capitals match in sequence.

I use `s=(random.choice(states))` to get a randome state into the variable `s`.
What I would like is to have the orresponding capital in `c`.

So if the value of `s=Alabama` then I would like the value of `c=Montgomery`

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output

Comment: `corrent_dict[s] = c` may be simpler than `corrent_dict.update({s:c})`...

Comment: @Rakesh I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the problem description correctly than pick an index, don't pick a state. Then you can get both the state and the capital:

```
import random

states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona']
capitals = ['Montgomery', 'Juneau', 'Phoenix']

indx = random.choice(range(len(states)))

s, c = states[indx], capitals[indx]

print(s, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a random integer between 1 and number of states in the list:

```
import random
number_of_states = range(len(states_list))
rand_num = random.randint(1, number_of_states)
```

Assign `s` and `c` to corresponding state and capital with `rand_num`:

```
s = states_list[rand_num]
c = capitals_list[rand_num]
```

Update the dictionary:

```
corrent_dict.update({s:c})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()` and `random.choice()`:

```
import random

states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona']
capitals = ['Montgomery', 'Juneau', 'Phoenix']

state, capital = random.choice([*zip(states, capitals)])
print('State={} Capital={}'.format(state, capital))
```

Prints for example:

```
State=Alabama Capital=Montgomery
```